# Manipulate Tinymce Document DOM with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a tinymce textarea that has a span tag like so: `<span data-range-id="4oYnl5fH0">...</span>`.

When the range of text is clicked, I want to show a pop up window next to the text.

The problem is that the **text is hidden inside an iframe, so JQuery can't access it.**

Is there any way to change the contents of something in an iframe with JQuery, specifically with tinymce? I can't just copy the contents and then paste it back in because I need **to get the coordinates of where the text is on the screen** To do so, I would use this:

```
position = $(this).offset();
```

Where `this` is the span tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and easy.

```
var editor = tinymce.editors[0]; // or tinymce.get('your_editor_id') or tinymce.activeEditor

var $ed_body = $(editor.getBody());

// do whatever you want with the editor content located inside the body
```

Comment: i'm getting this error `tinymce editor error cannot read property doc is undefined` can you suggest me. code `var body = tinymce activeEditor.dom.doc.body`

Comment: when are you calling this code? is your editor initialized already?